# How do you pick the sample size for a Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to write a program to analyse sounds – voice, music, etc. I have a good understanding of how the Fourier transform can break a sound into frequencies, amplitudes and phases but I don't know what a good sample size would be. I believe one of the tricks to the Fast Fourier Transform is picking sample sizes that are exact powers of two.

[The Wikipedia article on human hearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range) says that hearing is normally stated to be between 20 Hz and 20 000 Hz, although it may go as low as 12 Hz. If I record sound at 44 100 samples per second (CD sample rate) this gives me a wavelength of 2205 — 3675 samples at 20 and 12 Hz respectively. Does this mean that 4096 ($2^{12}$) would be a good sample size to analyse voice and music?

On the other hand, [this article on speech perception](https://sites.google.com/a/students.colgate.edu/speech-perception/) states that we can hear up to 30 phonemes per second, although some may be in parallel. I remember reading at some point what the duration of the shortest phoneme is and that it is supposed to relate to lowest sound we can hear, but I can't find this information at the moment. I imagine it would be useful to have a sample size small enough to fit at least twice into any phoneme.

Comment: do you know the wavelet transform, and more generally the constant-Q transform ? it is what graphic equalizers typically do : higher bitrate and bandwith in the highest frequency bands. and when computing the STFT for a 44Khz .wav signal, we typically choose a 2^10,2^11,2^12 or 2^13 (hanning or hamming) window size. and the STFT/wavelet/constant-Q transform all are special cases of "filter-bank transforms"

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not familiar with the wavelet transform or the constant-Q transform. I've never implemented a Fast Fourier Transform before, although I've had good success with a very slow method. Are you saying that you use different sample windows for different frequencies? So a large window for low frequencies and a small window for high frequencies?

Comment: no, but make your own experiments, you'll see. I'm just saying that the STFT (I didn't speak about the FFT) is a filter-bank whose output has been downsampled by a factor still allowing perfect reconstruction

Comment: and if you really want to write such a program, you have to download and play with matlab ($\ge$ 2007)